# How to select and copy the text from a textbox with Python + Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to select a web attribute with python via webdriver, specifically I want to copy the name that I entered to the recipent, but I can't do.

[image]

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.gmail.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
loginBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierId"]')
loginBox.send_keys('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
nextButton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierNext"]')
nextButton[0].click()
passWordBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="password"]/div[1]/div / div[1]/input')
passWordBox.send_keys('xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
nextButton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id ="passwordNext"]')
nextButton[0].click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[1]').send_keys('Grecia Abad del toro')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[1]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

How can I literally select and copy the text that is in the mail recipient? Thanks very much.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) why do you need to read the text you just entered into the element by yourself? 2) Are the last 2 lines in your code working correct?

Comment: It is an academic email. When you put the name of the person it throws you the mail and I need to copy them

Comment: Yes, the last two lines of the code work correctly. In fact all the code is functional, I just need to select it and copy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This element is containing the contact email address:

```
//form[@method='POST']//span[@email]
```

So, to get the addressee email address you can do the as following:

```py
driver.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[1]').send_keys('Grecia Abad del toro')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[1]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@method="POST"]//span[@email]').get_attribute("email")
print(email)
```

Comment: File "gmail.py", line 41
    email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@method='POST']//span[@email]').get_attribute("email")
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Corrected that, sorry